# How to use my own key to deploy via CapRover?

Tags: github, ssh-keys, caprover

I'm setting up an automated deployment using CapRover, but it seems not working due to my SSH key.

How could I generate a key accepted by CapRover and Github?

[image: CapRover Deployments]

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure to use PEM format, as other formats may not work.**

You can make it work by generating a deploy key using the command below.

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t ed25519 -C "yourname@example.com" -f ./deploykey -q -N ""
```